# Get the lowest/biggest price within an item of a List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Highlight (on HTML) the item whose its price it is the lowest or biggest of a list of items.

### The scenario

There is a `List<Products>` on my application. Four items of this list are illustrated by:

> **Item 01**
>
> - Product Name: Xbox 360
> - Market Name: Bestbuy
> - Price: US$159,90
>
> **Item 02**
>
> - Product Name: Xbox 360
> - Market Name: Walmart
> - Price: US$129,90
>
> **Item 03**
>
> - Product Name: Xbox 360
> - Market Name: eBay
> - Price: US$125,00
>
> **Item 04**
>
> - Product Name: Xbox 360
> - Market Name: Amazon
> - Price: US$119,90

As you can see, there is a biggest price as well as a lowest price — and I want to highlight them on HTML with some classes.

### Code spotlight

The markup is:

```
<div class="body">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><img src="@item.marketName" /></td>
                <td>US$@item.productPrice</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

The `foreach` above iterates with the list (`Model.ProductList`) that I've mentioned before.

### The question

With all those information, how can I get the lowest/biggest price of some `item` of this `foreach`?

### What I've already tried

I have already tried this:

```
@Model.ProductList.Min()
```

But this fragment of code doesn't make sense — *is it to get the min of what?*. Maybe something like this (of course doesn't work, but just to illustrate):

```
@Model.ProductList.productPrice.Min()
```

### Ambiguous question?

I searched on Google and StackOverflow about this subject, but without success — no results found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a lambda expression to `Min()` to calculate the value to minimize:

```
Model.ProductList.Min(p => p.ProductPrice)
```